# how to print the output of SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have the following code which parses a xml file :

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
DefaultHandler dh=new DefaultHandler();
parser.parse("newfile.xml",dh);
```

I am stuck here. Isn't there any method in SAX similar to `document.getElementByTagName` in DOM which allows me to print all the nodes and their values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SAX parser provides a mechanism to receive events (i.e. `startElement`, `characters`, `endElement`, etc) based on a depth-first traversal of an XML document.  Unlike DOM there isn't an object model that can be instrospected, if you don't hang on to the data from an event it is gone forever.  If you want to print the output of a SAX parser then you will need to put this logic in your implementation of `ContentHandler`.

**Note:**

`DefaultHandler` doesn't do anything by itself.  It is just an empty implementation of `ContentHandler` that you can extend so that you only have to override the event methods that you are interested in.

Comment: Thank You. I implemented all the three functions inside the default handler and it worked